# Django test client on an actual server

Tags: django, django-views, django-testing

I'm testing deploying my first Django project using Apache.

I use [Django's test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) to perform an "internal" GET from my own server, which worked OK locally, but not runnning on the actual server.

The client ends up getting Django error messages, like

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://testserver/polls/forms/test1/

How can I get the client's *GET* to work on the actual server, having the it be performed on the actual http: //my_actual_server_name.something/polls/forms/test1 instead of "testserver" ?

I tried setting `SERVER_NAME= ‘my_actual_server_name.something’` in the settings.py file but that's not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's test client doesn't actually make HTTP requests, it just makes a request object and passes it to your middleware/views.

If your goal is to make an http request to your own server, an easy way is to install [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) and do something like

```
# Some server on the network
requests.get("http://myserver.com/polls/forms/test1/")

# or some server running on the same machine
requests.get("http://12.0.0.1:8000/polls/forms/test1/")
```

If you just want to use the functionality of some view, you should move that logic into a function and call that from both the view and your other code.

### Very tangential side note:

If you're curious about how the test client doesn't make http requests, you can look at [the test client's code in the django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L300) (`client.get()` calls `client.generic()` which calls `client.request()` which instantiates `WSGIRequest()` and then passes that object to your app - which is the `request` that you receive in your views).

Comment: First off thank you for answering. I'm using a third party App that generates some html (in one of its views) and serves it. In my own App, I just want to take that html and store it (getting it from a URL that the other App serves). It doesn't need to be an actual http request. If there's a way to make the test client work on the web server as it did locally, it'd be great

Comment: @S_alj if you want to make a request to another app that accepts http requests, the `requests.get()` method is the way to go. Just run the app (if it's django and not exposed to the broader internet, `manage.py runserver` is just fine, no need for apache) and make requests to it

Comment: I've got it to work on the actual server with requests! I'm using the content part of the result (as in response=requests.get(url) -> response.content). Really appreciate your help!